# async promise try catch await return confusion

Tags: typescript, function, asynchronous, promise

I have been having trouble grasping the the concept of async functions and how to correctly implement them.

In an Angular app, I have the following function in a service that does resolve correctly, but I am confused as to whether or not this implementation is wrong, and if not, is there a better approach for writing it all together.

The function, simplified for clarity:

```
async doSomething(param:string): Promise<any> {
  this.activeParam = param;
  return this.doSomethingElse(param).then((response)=> {
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  }).catch((error) =>{
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
}
```

And I call that function in my component as follows:

```
this.service.doSomething('setting').then((result) =>{     
        console.log('success:', result);
      },(error)=>{
        console.log('error:', result);
});
```

**UPDATE**

I should have got some rest before posting this question as it is flawed from the start.

So id like to add an update to avoid confusing anyone else running into similar issues and arriving here as a result.

First thanks to @MicheleLambertucci for taking the time to clarify and providing a solid answer.

Second, id like to share the following link which IMO explains async functions in a beautifully simple way.

[Await vs Return vs Return Await](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/)

[And further detail here from the same author](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions)

Comment: There's no point writing an async function without an await in it, and no point in the no-op then or catch in doSomething. Note also that the canonical async abstraction in Angular is *observables*, not promises.

Comment: *"as i am at the end of a 14 hour coding bender here"* I guess you should take a break then, this is not healthy.

Comment: True... just completely exhausted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all drop the returns inside the `catch` and `then` callbacks. Also, you do nothing but return the values, which means that you can directly return the promise:

```js
doSomething(param: string): Promise<any> {
  this.activeParam = param;
  return this.doSomethingElse(param);
}
```

With that said, since you are using an `async` function, you could rewrite this function using the `await`. This would -in my opinion- result in better readable code.

```js
async doSomething(param: string): Promise<any> {
  this.activeParam = param;
  const response = await this.doSomethingElse(param);
  return response;
}
```

There are a few things to notice in this refactor:

- When you `await` a promise, the return of the expression is the value, not the promise
- An `await`-ed function throws an error if the promise got rejected, which means that this function's return value (a Promise) throws if the promise is rejected (no need to try/catch since you are just passing the error up)
- The `async` keyword "promisifies" the function, thus the return of the function is still a Promise (even though `response` is a value inside the function)

Comment: Actually I'd say the await is slightly less readable - with an async function, it doesn't matter whether you return the value or the promise from the caller's perspective. There'd only be a difference if you were going to have more handling (either on the awaited value or a catch) inside the async function.

Comment: An `async` function that does not `await` anything makes no sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I get what you are saying, but you would have the same result in a -in my opinion- more clean way just returning the Promise object directly without the async keyword. I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Ok, @MicheleLambertucci first, THANK you for taking the time here, and your note "When you await a promise, the return of the expression is the value, not the promise" has helped me to get a grasp on things .... i probably need rest, hah.

Comment: @MicheleLambertucci, trying to grasp your last 2 bullet points... "no need to try and catch ... if i understand you correctly, when calling your async version above, i would not need to use try/catch correct?

Comment: @DevMike In this particular example there is no need to use `try/catch` just because there is no handling, just passing by. If they wanted to handle the error in a particular way, then you would use it as normal
`async doSomething(param: string): Promise<any> {
  this.activeParam = param;
  try {
    const response = await this.doSomethingElse(param);
    return response;
  } catch(error) {
    console,log("No object was found");
    return undefined;
}`
In this example, if the Promise returned by `doSomethingElse` rejects, we log it and return `undefined`. (sry for the inline code)

Comment: ok - so if i finally understand all of this correctly.... in your async version, the return `response`  is a promise and not response data, but rather than speculate i am off to test this by forcing an error.

Comment: .... and ... yes... it does return as a promise. Ugh, i should have got some rest before posting this question to SO. Thanks again to all of you that took the time to respond.